# Linux Mysql Memory requirements

Tags: redhat, mysql, rhel5

I have:

- 32 bit - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)
- Mysql 5
- 10G RAM

What are the memory allocation limits with respect to mysql?
Maximum memory usage possible.
Any supporting documents from redhat site?

Comment: I assume 10G means 10 gigabyte of RAM ? ^^

Comment: And by the way, I do not know, but since when does a 32bit system supports more than 4GB of RAM? Without using any extension. Like Ubuntu has since the last release...

Comment: Do not take it as criticism, I just wanted to say, that this information is available to everyone with just a minimum amount of spending into google ;)

Answer (score 0):

> As such, if your system **has more than**
>   **4GB of RAM**, you need to install the
>   ... EXT3 file system capacity has been
>   extended beyond **8TB to a maximum of**
>   **16TB**. ..... the mysqli extension, a
>   new interface designed specifically
>   for MySQL

**Source:** http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-5-manual/release-notes/RELEASE-NOTES-x86-en.html

*EDIT: It took me 3s of googleling... (did I write correctly?)*

Comment: If everyone googles... ok leave it it took me 1s to post question here and proceed to some priority tasks... Thanks.
Mean while check this:
http://www.redhat.com/rhel/compare/

Here it exposes memory limits and all that - but again as its about a single application - mysql. How much is the memory limits about that? It cannot utilize >2G of ram, limit on datafile size and all that what i want to know.
I don't want to extend. I want to know limits.